# Print words only starting with starting with pre Java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Create a class StringDemo that contains the following static methods:
•   A method that takes in a sentence, tokenises it using a single space, and then prints only the words that start with “pre”.
•   The main method where you declare 2 variables and initialise them to sentences of your choice; then test the method that you have defined in previous step using the 2 sentences.

My attempt

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class StringDemo{
public static void main(String... args){
    String S1 = "We love prefix  that have car strongly wheels and car 
 seats";
    String S2 = "I have a lovely designed car that has many car features 
  beautifully and the car has a good car";

    printWordsWithPre(S1);
    printWordsWithPre(S2);

    System.out.println(printWordsWithPre(S1));
    System.out.println(printWordsWithPre(S1));

    }
  //-   Tokenises a string/sentence and prints only the words that end with 
   ly.
    public static void printWordsWithPre(String str){
    String[] sTokens = str.split("\\p{javaWhitespace}");
    for(int i = 0; i < sTokens.length; i++){
        if(sTokens[i].endsWith("pre")){
            System.out.println(sTokens[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good. Now tell us your evaluation of the code and what you see as the problem to be addressed. Or are you just wanting us to generally critique it?

Comment: You can't have this: `System.out.println(printWordsWithPre(S1));` The method you're calling returns `void`, so you can't `println` that. The `println` statement is already in the method call, so just delete those two lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class StringDemo{

    public static void main(String... args){
        String S1 = "We love prefix  that have car strongly wheels and car  seats";
        String S2 = "I have a lovely designed car that has many beautifully predesigned car features and the car has a good prebuilt car";

        printWordsWithPre(S1);
        printWordsWithPre(S2);

        // These functions don't return any data so they can't be printed. The results are already printed in the function above.
        /*System.out.println(printWordsWithPre(S1));
        System.out.println(printWordsWithPre(S1));*/
    }
    // Tokenises a string/sentence and prints only the words that starts with pre.
    public static void printWordsWithPre(String str){
        String[] sTokens = str.split("\\p{javaWhitespace}");
        for(int i = 0; i < sTokens.length; i++){
            //check if it starts with rather than ends with
            if(sTokens[i].startsWith("pre")){
                System.out.println(sTokens[i]);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I've made the following changes:

- Added a few words starting with pre;
- Removed the System.out.println's
  in main because they tried to print a void return;
- changed endsWith
  to startsWith.

Answer (score 2):

You used `endsWith` instead of `startsWith`